# Is there a way to filter for 50% response rate in R?

Tags: r, proportions

I made a tibble with a representation of a survey I'm working on with 6 questions [Q1:Q6, with 2 expressions], 4 different organizational units [Org_unit, 1:4] and another question which tries to find out, whether the person in the respecitve company is a manager or not [Manager, 1:2], in which [1] stands for manager and [2] for employee.

the tibble looks like this:
Note: [-9] is a non-response and I therefore assigned them to NA.

```
library(dplyr)

Org_unit <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
Manager <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2)
Q1 <-  c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
Q2 <- c(1,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9) #Note one response
Q3 <- c(1,1,2,-9,-9,2,1,1, -9, 1)
Q4 <- c(1,1,-9,1,2,2,-9,1,-9,2)
Q5 <- c(1,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9)
Q6 <- c(1,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9)

df <- tibble(Org_unit, Manager, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6)
df[df == -9] <- NA
df

# A tibble: 10 x 8
   Org_unit Manager    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1        1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2        1       1     2    NA     1     1    NA    NA
 3        1       2     1    NA     2    NA    NA    NA
 4        1       2     2    NA    NA     1    NA    NA
 5        2       1     1    NA    NA     2    NA    NA
 6        2       1     2    NA     2     2    NA    NA
 7        2       1     1    NA     1    NA    NA    NA
 8        3       1     2    NA     1     1    NA    NA
 9        3       2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
10        4       2     2    NA     1     2    NA    NA
```

The purpose is to find out, how many of those employees (Condition #1, Manager has to be [2]) answered a question with [1]. It's basically the amount of employees, who answered the particular question with [1] within their respective org_unit.

Example: org_unit 1 has 4 members in total. Out of those 4, only 2 meet the employee-criteria (Manager == 2). 1 of those 2 employees in org_unit 1 has answered Q1 with [1], in other words, 50% of the employees in org_unit 1 have answered Q1 with [1].

```
prop <-df %>%
  group_by(Org_unit) %>%
  filter(Manager == 2) %>%
  summarise(N = n(), 
        across(c(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6), ~mean(. == 1))) 

prop
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  Org_unit     N    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
     <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1        1     2   0.5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2        3     1   1      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3        4     1   0      NA     1     0    NA    NA
```

As we see, Q1 has a prop of 0,5 and a total of N = 2 members in Org_unit 1. So this seems to work.

The problem is, individuals who answered less than 50% of all questions, should not be counted as members of their respective group. Let's take a look at the tibble again.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 8
   Org_unit Manager    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1        1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2        1       1     2    NA     1     1    NA    NA
 3        1       2     1    NA     2    NA    NA    NA
 4        1       2     2    NA    NA     1    NA    NA
 5        2       1     1    NA    NA     2    NA    NA
 6        2       1     2    NA     2     2    NA    NA
 7        2       1     1    NA     1    NA    NA    NA
 8        3       1     2    NA     1     1    NA    NA
 9        3       2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
10        4       2     2    NA     1     2    NA    NA
```

Individual 3, although it meets the employee-criteria (Manager == 2) and there is at least one question answered with (Q1 == 1), Q2, and Q4:Q6 are NA's and therefore more than 50% of all questions are non-responses.

I need to adjust the prop code to reduce the number of N by all non-responses (in this case org_unit 1 should have been reduced by 2, since both individual 3 and 4, although they meet some criteria, have 4/6 non-responses. It' also important, that org_unit 1 still keep showing up in the dataframe, but instead be listed as NA for N and the proportions should be adjusted according to the right amount of members in the specific group.

Is there a way to work around this? Thanks in advance!

Edit: The threshold should be < .5

and the result should look like this:

```
prop
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  Org_unit     N    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
     <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1        1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2        2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
3        3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4        4     1     0    NA     1     0    NA    NA
```

Comment: Could you be more clear what the result is supposed to look like? Is the threshold `< .5` or `<= .5`? Ideally, post the table that you want as a result

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to calculate the `N` not as `dplyr::n()`, but as the number of repsondents where `Manager == 2` and which have answered (`!is.na`) at least 50% of the questions `Q1:Q6`.

We could do this using `dplyr::rowwise` and then calculate per row whether the `sum` of `NA` is smaller or equal to `3`. Then we can resume the original calculation and `group_by(Org_unit)`, calculate `N` as `sum(N)` per group and then use `N` inside the function in `across` as `sum(.x == 1, na.rm = TRUE) / N`  instead of using the `mean`.

The provided data is not very good for this specific example, since most of the respondents have 50% or more `NA`s in their responses. Often `N` will be `0` and therefore we need an `if` `else` flow to account for the cases where we divide through `N == 0`.

```r
library(dplyr)

prop <- df %>%
  filter(Manager == 2) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(N = sum(is.na(c_across(Q1:Q6))) <= 3) %>% 
  group_by(Org_unit) %>%
  summarise(N = sum(N),
            across(c(Q1:Q6), ~ if(N > 0) {
              sum(.x == 1, na.rm = TRUE) / N
              } else NA_real_))

prop

#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>   Org_unit     N    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
#>      <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1        1     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 2        3     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 3        4     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As suggested by @mnist here is a more scalable version:

```
df %>%
  filter(Manager == 2) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(N = mean(is.na(c_across(starts_with("Q")))) <= 0.5) %>% 
  group_by(Org_unit) %>%
  summarise(N = sum(N),
            across(starts_with("Q"), ~ if(N > 0) {
              sum(.x == 1, na.rm = TRUE) / N
            } else NA_real_))
```

Comment: The issue is that you have hardcoded the columns and <=3 would be neat to be scalable to an unknown number of Question columns, right? is there a way to know within `across` how many columns were selected by `across`?

Comment: @mnist: This only concerns the `mutate` call with `c_across`, so instead of doing `<= 3` we could say `<= length(c_across(Q1:Q6))/2`. Of course `Q1:Q6` are hard coded here in the example, but `<tidyselect>` allows us to select any number of columns, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I transformed it to my main dataset and I'm getting an error, that "..3 must be a vector, not a 'formula' object". Guess I'll have to build the whole thing from scratch, it really confuses me at this point

Comment: @Sascha: I assume that there is a problem with the call to  `across`. Did you change it in any way? Does it start with `~` and does it contain `.x`? You can try to name the function argument by adding `.fn = ` before the tilde `~`. Without seeing the data or the full error this is all I can think of. Maybe you can add the info from  `rlang::last_error()`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

First in the `group_by` we add the statement `.drop = FALSE` to not remove the Org_units from the original table. Then we do a `rowMeans` to check whether or not 50% or more questions have been answered.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Org_unit, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  filter(rowMeans(is.na(across(matches("Q\\d+")))) <= 0.5) %>%
  filter(Manager == 2) %>%
  summarise(N = n(), across(matches("Q\\d+"), ~mean(. == 1)))
```

Resulting in:

```
  Org_unit     N    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
     <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1        1     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2        2     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3        3     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4        4     1     0    NA     1     0    NA    NA
```

Comment: does not exactly how OPs desired result but my main issue is that you have hardcoded the columns and `<=3` would be neat to be scalable to an unknown number of Question columns, right?

Comment: Although this works on the example dataframe, once I transfer this code to the real dataframe , it skips some org_units and they don't show up.  I'm still trying to figure out why

Comment: @mnist added scalability

Comment: @Sascha try doing the `group_by` before the first filter. I can imagine that's what skips some of the Org_units. I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks, this stopped skipping the Org_units! But unfortunately the N Column does not count the correct number of members. I compared it manually with the raw dataframe and somehow the N's are off and therefore the proportion isn't correct either

Comment: Can you share an example of an Org_unit where it's incorrect? Please add it in the original question

Comment: Ok, I'll try to build another dataset where the problem occcurs. The original one is pretty big and I'll post it once it's done and it fits the needs

Comment: The only difference I could find is that my main dataset contains some recoding to the extent, that 1 becomes 0 and 2 becomes 1. I recoded the sample dataset from above and it't didn't change much, so that's probably not an issue. Another difference I found is that the main dataset even does not skip counting when there is not even a single person in, for example, Org_unit 60. There are 2 possible scenarios in case of not counting an Org_unit. Let's say for Org_unit 60. #1: Individuals from Org_unit 60 did participated in the study, but are managers, so R doesn't count them, but lists 1/x

Comment: them, thats what .drop does I guess. Scenario #2: There are no individuals in Org_unit 60, neither employees, nor managers. But since there are 200 Org_units in total, R should also lists them under NA to not skip the list.  That's the only other difference I found. It's really weird..

Comment: I'll keep looking for a reproducible dataset where the same error occurs..

Comment: If you want to create a table that includes `Org_Units` that are not in any way listed in the questionaire dataset than I would suggest creating a second table and fill them with the table created above using `left_join`.

Answer (score 1):

Idea is simliar to @Tim but instead `rowwise` uses `pmap_int`

```
df %>%
  filter(Manager == 2) %>%
  mutate(
    count = pmap_int(
      select(., matches("^Q[0-9]+$")),
      ~sum(is.na(c(...))) * 2 <= length(c(...))
    ) 
  ) %>%
  group_by(Org_unit) %>%
  summarise(
    N = sum(count),
    N = ifelse(N > 0, N, NA_integer_),
    across(matches("^Q[0-9]+$"), ~sum(.x == 1) / N)
  )
```

Comment: like the scalability since you did not specify the column names or number of columns!

Comment: it's possible to generalize more with adding `min_answer_perc = 0.5` and then changing to `sum(is.na(c(...))) / length(c(...)) <= 1-min_answer_perc `