# Using dplyr to make row wise conditions amidst missing values

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, purrr, plyr

I have a large dataset of individuals, their age, and scores across 5 tests and some missing data. The dataset looks like this:

```
id<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
age<-c(25, 43, 55, 12, 15, 67, 71)
score1<-c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)
score2<-c(5, NA, NA, 5, 6, 7, 5)
score3<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 7, 6)
score4<-c( 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA)
score5<-c(5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, NA)
df<-data.frame(id, age, score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)
df
```

```
  id age score1 score2 score3 score4 score5
1  1  25      1      5     NA      5      5
2  2  43      2     NA     NA     NA      5
3  3  55      1     NA     NA     NA      4
4  4  12      2      5     NA     NA      4
5  5  15      1      6      6     NA      5
6  6  67      2      7      7      6      5
7  7  71      2      5      6     NA     NA
```

For scores 2-5, I want to create a `Missing` condition where, if each `id` has more than 30% missing data (NA) across scores 2-5, then `Missing`=YES else `Missing`=NO

The desired output should look like this:

```
  id age score1 score2 score3 score4 score5 missing
1  1  25      1      5     NA      5      5      no
2  2  43      2     NA     NA     NA      5     yes
3  3  55      1     NA     NA     NA      4     yes
4  4  12      2      5     NA     NA      4     yes
5  5  15      1      6      6     NA      5      no
6  6  67      2      7      7      6      5      no
7  7  71      2      5      6     NA     NA     yes
```

What is the best way to create row-wise conditions in dplyr? I tried using `dplyr::mutate` and `ifelse` in `df %>% rowwise() %>% missing=ifelse(sum(is.na(.x))/length(.x)* 100 >=30), "yes", "no")` but I think this is wrong and does not seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to filter for 50% response rate in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69099767/is-there-a-way-to-filter-for-50-response-rate-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
rowwise %>%
mutate(missing=ifelse(mean(is.na(across(score2:score5)))>0.3,'yes','no')) %>% 
ungroup
```

**output;**

```
    id   age score1 score2 score3 score4 score5 missing
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
1     1    25      1      5     NA      5      5 no     
2     2    43      2     NA     NA     NA      5 yes    
3     3    55      1     NA     NA     NA      4 yes    
4     4    12      2      5     NA     NA      4 yes    
5     5    15      1      6      6     NA      5 no     
6     6    67      2      7      7      6      5 no     
7     7    71      2      5      6     NA     NA yes
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowMeans(condition)`. I suggest you use the `num_range` selection here, it fits your column selection statement perfectly.

```
df %>% mutate(missing=ifelse(rowMeans(across(num_range('score', 2:5), is.na))>0.3, 'yes', 'no'))

  id age score1 score2 score3 score4 score5 missing
1  1  25      1      5     NA      5      5      no
2  2  43      2     NA     NA     NA      5     yes
3  3  55      1     NA     NA     NA      4     yes
4  4  12      2      5     NA     NA      4     yes
5  5  15      1      6      6     NA      5      no
6  6  67      2      7      7      6      5      no
7  7  71      2      5      6     NA     NA     yes
```

Answer (score 2):

*(My suggestion is nearly identical to that offered by GuedesBF, but I didn't see it when I hit "Post". I'm keeping it visible for the sake of the benchmark and discussion.)*

An alternative that does not use `rowwise`.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Missing = rowMeans(is.na(subset(., select=score2:score5))) > 0.3)
#   id age score1 score2 score3 score4 score5 Missing
# 1  1  25      1      5     NA      5      5   FALSE
# 2  2  43      2     NA     NA     NA      5    TRUE
# 3  3  55      1     NA     NA     NA      4    TRUE
# 4  4  12      2      5     NA     NA      4    TRUE
# 5  5  15      1      6      6     NA      5   FALSE
# 6  6  67      2      7      7      6      5   FALSE
# 7  7  71      2      5      6     NA     NA    TRUE
```

The advantage is performance. Row-wise operations in general will be slower, and if your data is *significantly* larger then it may be an issue.

```r
bench::mark(
  rowwise = df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(missing=mean(is.na(across(score2:score5)))>0.3) %>% ungroup(), 
  rowMeans = df %>% mutate(Missing = rowMeans(is.na(subset(., select=score2:score5))) > 0.3),
  guedes = df %>% mutate(missing=rowMeans(across(num_range('score', 2:5), is.na))>0.3),
  check=FALSE)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                  time           gc                
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                  <list>         <list>            
# 1 rowwise      5.91ms   6.61ms      146.   10.05KB     0       74     0      507ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [21 x 3]> <bch:tm [74]>  <tibble [74 x 3]> 
# 2 rowMeans      1.7ms      2ms      439.    1.64KB     2.30   191     1      435ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [4 x 3]>  <bch:tm [192]> <tibble [192 x 3]>
# 3 guedes       2.97ms   3.44ms      272.   13.24KB     0      137     0      503ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [21 x 3]> <bch:tm [137]> <tibble [137 x 3]>
```

where the `rowMeans` method is around 3x the speed.

Comment: Hi, r2evans, i suspect the rowMeans solution should be the most efficient, wouldnt it?

Comment: In my answer I used `across` instead of `subset(., x)`, i wonder whether it would make any difference

Comment: Yes, it does make a difference ... it's faster than `rowwise` but still half the speed of `subset`.

Comment: Interesting to know `across` still comes with a downside in performance (although i believe it excels in clarity and readability). This was acknowledged in earlier versions of dplyr, yet the tidyverse team claimed the performance gap was closed (or mitigated) as of dplyr 1.0.4: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/

Comment: Maybe it is because, in my solution, `is.na(across)` is still a multi-step column-wise operation, while with subset, `is.na(subset)` is a single call over the entire sub-dataframe

Comment: Anyway, i just ran your code with only one selected column per operation (across(score2)), and still got the same difference in performance.

Comment: Perhaps. I suggest that benchmarking on 7 rows of data is likely clouded by basic function overhead; it's possible (even likely) that any penalty will be reduced or reversed with larger datasets.